# Why IIS8.5 try use dynamic compression for static JSON and SVG files?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core, iis-8.5

I have one more question about IIS compression

I have static file ../wwwroot/src/locale/en-us.json and sgv

But IIS8.5 recognizes it as a dynamic content and try to use dynamic compression

What I must do to force IIS works with .json and .svg in the same way like .js and .css

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in mime types, by default IIS doesn't apply dynamic compression for application/json and xml/svg+xml

I don't have access to web server configuration and I made a workaround in local web.config

```
  <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="text/json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="text/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>
```